# Image Normal map to DirectX 9-12

Tags: directx, directx-11, directx-9, directx-10, directx-12

I have a question for you because I really need this and I have no idea how can I solve it.
Is it any possibility to convert a Normal map image into a NormalBuffer? Or in other words...  I want to make a 3D application in DirectX 9-12 which will use for textures of a model (material of model) some images which will be exported from Substance Painter. Is it any possibility to do this?

Comment: Did Chuck's answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

To render with Substance, you need a PBR shader and that's what determines your required inputs. Typically you need an albeto (diffuse) map, a normal map, and a set of material maps for roughness/metalness or specular/glossiness, as well as typically an ambient-occlusion (AO) map or channel. See [PBR Guide](https://www.allegorithmic.com/pbr-guide).

You might want to take a look at the [SimplePBR12](https://github.com/Microsoft/Xbox-ATG-Samples/tree/master/Samples/Graphics/SimplePBR12) sample for a working example.

> BTW, you should *really not* try to create an app that uses Direct3D 9, DIrect3D 10, Direct3D 11, and Direct3D 12. You are much better off these days just sticking with DirectX 11 unless you are a graphics expert who needs the additional control of DirectX 12.